# how to send data to controller using uploadify

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, uploadify

I want to send some data to controller when uploadify event is occur.How can i do this? For example i can send data using ajax through data properties.Now i want to send data using uploadify to controller.help me on this thanks in advance.

```
$("#image_upload1").uploadify({
            'buttonText':'Select',
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
            'swf':'<?php echo base_url()?>resources/flash/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader':'<?php echo site_url('item/update_item_image1')?>',
            'width': 40,
            'multi':false,
            'onUploadComplete':function(file)
            {
                $('#original').hide();
                $('#image1').attr('style','background-image:url("../resources/uploads/18/thumbnail/'+file.name+'")');
                $('#hidden_img_value1').attr('value',file.name)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [formdata](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/) option like this

```
$("#image_upload1").uploadify({
        'formData'      : {'someKey' : 'someValue', 'someOtherKey' : 1},
        'swf'           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php'
    });
```

And as the doc says You can access those values using the `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays in PHP.

Comment: are u sure @Joy,because i found that using scriptdata i can send data to the controller

Comment: You can check on the link in my answer, did you try with formdata, I have seen `scriptdata` too. But it's not in the doc anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it

Basically, at the end of all uploads, in the onAllComplete method, I build up all the info I need, including the filenames and some other variables and Post it to the controller method using an a jquery ajax call.  In my example, the values of vId, vYear and uploadedFileNames are set elsewhere in my document, but you could replace them with whatever data you need to pass back to the controller.

```
$('#file_input_que').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/core/javascript/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/core/javascript/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/core/javascript/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/listings/tmp',
    'auto'      : true,
    'multi'     : true,
    'queueSizeLimit' : <?=12-count($imagecount)?>,
    'fileExt'   : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif',
    'fileDesc'    : 'Image Files',
    'sizeLimit'   : 5242880,
    'onAllComplete': function(event, data) {
        var vId = $('#vehicleId').val();
        var vYear = $('#vehicleYear').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'<?=site_url('/dash/uploadImagesAjax')?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { vId: vId, vYear: vYear, uploadedFileNames: uploadedFileNames },
            success: function(data) {
                location.reload();
            } 

        }); 

        hideOverlay("ajaxoverlay");
    } 
  });
```

Comment: i dont want to pass data after completing my upload,whatever you did its correct but it will happen when uploading is complete.I got the solution-'formData'.you can see above comments for sample example